# Excel file download on click of a link in html

Tags: html, excel

I am trying to download an excel file on click of an image link.

[image]

I have put the file in **Files** folder under **Upload** and it downloads the file.

The code looks like

```
<div class="export-template-label" style="display:inline-block;margin:5px 5px -8px 0px;">
    <a href="../../Upload/Files/Group Membership Upload Template.xlsx" target="_self" download>
        <img src="Images/excel.png" alt="logo" style="float:left;" />
    </a>
</div>
```

But when I try to open the downloaded file, it shows

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

The file though opens perfectly fine if I try to right click and open it without downloading it through the image link.

[image]

Comment: At very first it seems like the Excel file is invalid/corrupted. Can you please explain more about it ? Did you used any PHPExcel library for creating the excel file ?

Comment: No I did not. It opens perfectly fine if I try to right click and open it without downloading it through the image link. Please see the updates in the question.

Comment: Try to rename the file.


Group_Membership_Upload_Template.xlsx

Comment: No luck sir. I tried it is still showing the same error even the downloaded file name does not contain underscores